# Using React-Hooks/Axios to fetch data and display in a table

Tags: javascript, json, axios, react-hooks

I have this React setup, I defined a hook called `ApiTable` and have a `renderTable` method. What I'm trying to do is get the data from the api endpoint, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` and return it into a table with the appropriate category.

Right now it's scrunching up all the columns onto the left side as seen here. Currently, the data isn't showing up and is compacted to the left side. I'm pretty sure I have the table data setup wrong.

Also, I'm not sure if the axios request is supposed to inside the useEffect or not.

`https://imgur.com/a/Up4a56v`

```js
const ApiTable = () => {

  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    setData([data]);

    axios.get(url)

    .then(json => console.log(json))

  }, []);

  const renderTable = () => {

      return data.map((user) => {

        const { name, email, address, company } = user;

        return (
          <div>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <th>Address</th>
                 <th>Company</th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>name</td>
              <td>email</td>
              <td>address</td>
              <td>company</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }


      return (
        <div>
            <h1 id='title'>API Table</h1>
            <Table id='users'>
              {renderTable()}
            </Table>
         </div>
      )

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are fetching data correctly, but setting data to state wrongly.

Also when you iterating your `data` array, you are printing `table head` each time which is wrong and from your `data` array `address` and `company` are object so you cant direct print the object.

You need to do this,

```
const App = () => {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'

  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then(json => setData(json.data))
  }, [])

  const renderTable = () => {
    return data.map(user => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{user.name}</td>
          <td>{user.email}</td>
          <td>{user.address.street}</td> //only street name shown, if you need to show complete address then you need to iterate over `user.address` object
          <td>{user.company.name}</td> //only company name shown, if you need to show complete company name then you need to iterate over `user.name` object
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="title">API Table</h1>
      <table id="users"> //Your Table in post changed to table to make it work
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Company</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderTable()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-c261z?fontsize=14)

Comment: appreciate the answer, makes total sense. For the axios part, `(json => setData(json.data)` is the `json` part necessary? Doesn't axios return a json automatically? or do we need to specify this?

Comment: `axios.get(url).then(json => setData(json.data))` , in this `json` is just a name given you can have anything you want. Axios response is stored in this variable which is then stored in state using `setData(json.data)`. If you change `json` with `response` then you should write this, `axios.get(url).then(response => setData(response.data))`. Here we are setting data from `response.data`, because we are getting data in `response` object with `data` as a key.

Comment: ahh gotcha, just a variable that you can name whatever, appreciate the clarity